# Offline Google Map on Android

Tags: google-maps, android, offline

If I go to abroad as a tourist before I collect the visiting places on my Google Maps then export it to KML.

In abroad I don't use mobile Internet on the street (very expensive) but I would like to check the places during my way so I need an offline map where my interested places pins on it.

There is an application: Google My Maps but it only works online, is it?

Is there any application or solution where there is an offlineable map and I can import my collected pins kml-file to check the places in the visited city?

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Maps.Me](http://maps.me/en/home). This does not use Google Maps, instead it is based on OpenStreetMap. It allows downloading maps to use offline - you can download a complete country or state at once.

You can add "Bookmarks" on the map for places you are interested in. You can import a KML file as bookmarks. ie email the KML to your phone, then open the file in Maps.Me. And that will add all of the points as bookmarks. These bookmarks work fine offline, and will show on the map and can be searched or used for directions etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can download a portion of Google Maps onto your Android phone by zooming to the area that you want to save and then in the search menu type "Ok maps" without the quotation marks. This will save a copy to your phone. Remember to be on WiFi when doing this, as a significant amount of data will be downloaded. Furthermore, no route-planning will be available when using an offline map.

With regards to saving KML / KMZ files onto your phone, and displaying them, I'd suggest using the Google Earth app, rather than the Google Maps app. In this case, you'd simply save your KML / KMZ file to your G-Drive, and load the file through the direct import function in the G-Earth app. I am not certain if it is possible to localize Google Earth visualizations, but you can adjust the cache-size.

Comment: I know this trick but it's not enough because I would like to import my places pins (kml file).

Answer (score 0):

One alternative would be to enable geolocation in your phones camera app and snap pictures where you would like to drop a point. You could then create points from the the coordinates that you would like to mark from Lat/Long (exif data) in your photos at a later time using Google Earth and export to .kml.

Comment: I need points before i go to that place...